# Writing a more efficient Neo4J Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','user:37f0ce60-b428-11e8-bb45-9394d4f42b57') YIELD rel, start, end 
WITH DISTINCT rel, start, end 
MATCH (ctx:Context) 
WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid AND (ctx.name="iG9CE55wbtY" ) 
RETURN DISTINCT start.uid AS source_id, start.name AS source_name, end.uid AS target_id, end.name AS target_name, rel.uid AS edge_id, ctx.name AS context_name, rel.statement AS statement_id, rel.weight AS weight;
```

Which uses indexed relationships. However, it takes about 4 to 10 seconds to process.

Here's the results with `PROFILE`:

[image]
[image]

`Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 470705 total db hits in 2758 ms.`

Is there anything I could optimize in this query, for instance, using parameters or rewriting it in any way that could improve the performance?

Comment: Can you share the results of running the query with PROFILE? Also, is rel.context a foreign key? You should probably convert those relationships into nodes if that is the case.

Comment: I added the results of running the query with PROFILE. and what does it mean a "foreign key"? It's one of the properties of the :Context type of nodes.

Comment: [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) is a generic database term.  Mostly used for Relational databases, in short it is property that contains an identifier to another item. Neo4j can use them, but they are discouraged because it is a strong sign you need a relationship between those two things. If it is on a relationship, it is a strong sign that relationship should actually be a node. Basically, Neo4j uses relationships as a better version of foreign keys.

Comment: Can you repost the profile with all of the boxes expanded please?

Comment: Try `MATCH (start)-[rel:TO{user:37f0ce60-b428-11e8-bb45-9394d4f42b57}->(end), (ctx:Context{ctx.name:"iG9CE55wbtY"}) WHERE  rel.context = ctx.uid RETURN *` If you can promote rel to a node, that would significantly boost performance. Also, does the TO relationship go to or from the user whose id it stores? Why is that in the relationship? If you could get the rel by matching the unique user first, that could also help significantly.

Comment: @Tezra this request doesn't work, I get an error.

Comment: The :TO relationship does not connect to a user. It's the relations between different nodes and the user property shows who made the relation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181094/discussion-between-tezra-and-dmitry-paranyushkin).